# Парсинг HTML с помощью JSOUP?

Tags: java, android, html, jsoup

Как парсить html-текст на наличие ссылок в android? Читал, что нужно использовать библиотеки типа Jsoup, HtmlСleaner, находил примеры, пробовал, но ничего не получается. Нашел следующий код:

```
Elements images = doc.select("img[src~=(?i)\\.(png|jpe?g|gif)]");
for (Element image : images) {

    String ssl =  image.attr("src");
}
```

Пробую им парсить - не получается.

Решил пойти другим способом: забить в текстовую переменную текст страницы, затем парсить переменную, страница благополучно считывается и даже выводится в текст вьюв следующим кодом:

```
htm = new RequestTask();
htm.execute("http://favim.ru/image/3800664/");       
try {

    final TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);      
    text = htm.get();
    StringBuffer html = new StringBuffer();
    html.append(text);
    textView.setText(html);
```

Но парсить у меня не получается. То ли делаю не так, то ли что.

Теперь мне нужно из переменной `text` вытащить ссылку на изображение, чтобы в дальнейшем вывести ее на экран. Подскажите, каким образом это сделать?

Или каким образом все же, используя библиотеку Jsoup, парсить страницу. Пробовал вот таким образом, но в переменной doc почему-то `null` забивается и все. Или приложение вылетает.

```
class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... param) {


        try {
            doc = Jsoup.connect("http://favim.ru/image/3800664/").get();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (doc != null)
        {
            Elements images = doc.select("img[src~=(?i)\\.(png|jpe?g|gif)]");
            for (Element image : images) {

                String ssl =  image.attr("src");

            }

            /*Elements imgTags = doc.select("img");*/
        }

        return null;
    }    

}
```

Comment: Если скомпилировать то, что вы привели в последнем примере без привязки к андроиду, то это работает. `doc == null` вообще нонсенс - думаю это значит что было брошено исключение и в переменную ничего не было записано.

Comment: разрешение на доступ в интернет есть у приложения? В `LogCat` что выводится? Стопудово стактрейс `e.printStackTrace();`, или стактрейс исключения должен вывестись.

Comment: Существенной помощью было бы, если бы вы разобрались почему не работал первый пример и написали ответ на свой вопрос.Сейчас ваш вопрос и комментарий не очень полезны

Answer (score 1):

Перенес код в класс, где считывается код html в переменную, там спарсил и все получилось. Может кому понадобиться:

```
text = htm.get();
StringBuffer html = new StringBuffer();
html.append(text);

Document doc = Jsoup.parse(text);
String ssl = null;

Elements images = doc.select("img[src~=(?i)\\.(png|jpe?g|gif)]");
for (Element image : images) {

    ssl =  image.attr("src");
}

if (ssl == null) ssl= "Нет доступа";

textView.setText(ssl);
```

---

Ответ из комментария участника [@Иван](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/197833/)